# Using manifest v3.0 to update chrome Current tab URL with javascript to the next number

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to create Chrome extention to update the a number in the url and navigate to it.

If the URL is -
https://www.asurascans.com/0907768668-youngest-scion-of-the-mages-chapter-6/

Then I expect the new URL after clicking on the extention will be -
https://www.asurascans.com/0907768668-youngest-scion-of-the-mages-chapter-7/

But sadly the result I get is from the extension click is -
https://www.asurascans.com/0907778668-youngest-scion-of-the-mages-chapter-6/

I tried -

index.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>URL Analyzer</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--   <button id="analyze_button">Analyze URL</button>
 --></body>
</html>
```

popup.js -

```
function analyzeUrl() {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, tabs => {
    let currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
    console.log('Analyzing URL:', currentUrl);
    var matches = currentUrl.match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/);
    if (matches) {
      var number = parseInt(matches[0]);
      var newNumber = number + 1;
      var newUrl = currentUrl.replace(/\d+$/, newNumber.toString());
      console.log('Modified URL:', newUrl);
      chrome.tabs.update({ url: newUrl });
    }
  });
}

console.log('starting....');
analyzeUrl();
console.log('end....');
```

but I don't get the wanted result sadly.

Also, not sure if related but I can't use inspect popup to see the prints in the console.
This is my manifest file -

```
{
  "name": "URL Analyzer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A Chrome extension that analyzes and modifies URLs.",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

edit: updated files, now the inspect works but not the best.

Comment: Protip: Search the web for "regex101". You'll find a website where you can test if your regular expressions actually do what they're supposed to do. In case it's not obvious what I'm saying: 1) Go to the regex101 wesbite. 2) Test your regular expressions with the URLs mentioned in your question. 3) If your regular expressions don't do what they're supposed to do, modify them until they do. You can do all of this on the regex101 website.

Comment: "I can't use inspect popup to see the prints in console" - Why not? What happens or doesn't happen when you inspect the popup? Are there any error messages?

Comment: 1) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. 2) Remove the entire `chrome.browserAction` line and add `analyzeUrl();` instead. 3) Replace popup.js with popup.html in `default_popup` and create a new file popup.html like `<script src=popup.js></script>`

Comment: @ThomasMueller the button is disabled for me

Comment: @ThomasMueller about the regex, it works but the replacing is not. it find the number (6) and replace it all over the link instead of only the last one